# How to hidden the navigation drawer menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer in base activity which is extended by all other activities. For the some scenarios i need to hide the navigation drawer for some screens.

How can i achieve this?

Drawerlistener

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;
import info.androidhive.materialdesign.adapter.NavigationDrawerAdapter;
import info.androidhive.materialdesign.model.NavDrawerItem;

public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles = null;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
        this.drawerListener = listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
        List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


        // preparing navigation drawer items
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // drawer labels
        titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return layout;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }


    }

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

BaseActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_950), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        if (getActionBar() != null) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        }
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }
}
```

Please help!

[image]

Comment: down voters, please mention what i did wrong here?

Comment: Try this `if (activity.getActionBar() != null) {
            activity.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            activity.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        }`

Comment: I am not a down voter but I think the reason is because the question is a bit not clear. Please show the code; this will help us understand the question better and be of further assistance.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't [show what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Comment: @2Dee code updated,pls check

Comment: Have you tried my comment?

Comment: @BNK tried not working

Comment: @Boopathi, Check updated answer

Comment: Say there are three activities act_1 (required) ,act_2 (not required) ,act_3(not required). 

So in order to accomplish this , you need to inflate different layout for act_2 , act_3 using setContentView(R.layout.xmlfilewhichdoesNOThavetheDRAWER);

Answer (score 1):

you also have to use drawer lock mode if you don't want drawer menu opened by dragging

```
 drawerView.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, drawerView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in onCreate():

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code where you dont want to show up drawer icon

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

**UPDATE:**
Your code must be something like this,

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) { 
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); 
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest also this code :

```
if (activity.getActionBar() != null) { 
    activity.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    activity.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false); }
```